# The American English learning counterpart of 'Cambridge English in Use'

Tags: discussion

I am seeking for help on searching resources for learning American English collocations, phrasal verbs, idioms, and pronunciation skills.

My background is mainly an advanced English learner who uses the language in everyday life as well as for conducting scientific research. However, due to my insufficient language competence/education background, I am still struggling with articulating myself with fluent and natural English expressions.

I have found the books 'Cambridge English Collocations/Phrasal Verbs/Idioms/Pronunciation in Use' particularly easy to use and practice for self-study (https://www.cambridge.org/gb/cambridgeenglish/catalog/grammar-vocabulary-and-pronunciation/english-collocations-use-intermediate), in that they classify expressions into units according to their functions and pragmatics, and teach those most frequently used expressions (for British English though) in proper contexts. Moreover, they have well-designed exercises to help solidify the acquisition.

On the other hand, I have been searching for their American English counterpart but haven't had much luck so far. The most common resources I found were dictionaries of American idioms, which could not really serve as self-study textbooks. The closest counterpart I have come across so far is 'Speak English like an American' by Amy Gillett, but the classification of expressions into units there is not so visible comparing with the Cambridge books, while the lack of marks of levels (intermidiate/basic vs advanced) is another problem.

I wonder if there is any resource for American English one can use if one wants to follow basically the same strategy in learning British English from the Cambridge books. Any types of resources are most helpful, although all kinds of suggestions and comments on different learning strategies are also welcome!